# SAP COM VB6 VB.NET Difference in behavior

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, sap-gui, bapi

I am connecting to SAP via COM, using ActiveX controls dragged into the Form.
In VB6 I write:

```
Private Sub Form_Terminate()
    SAPBAPIControl.Connection.Logoff
End Sub

Private Sub SAPLogonControl_Click()
    Set SAPBAPIControl.Connection = SAPLogonControl.NewConnection
    SAPBAPIControl.Connection.Client = "100"
    If SAPBAPIControl.Connection.Logon(0, False) Then
        MsgBox SAPBAPIControl.Connection.IsConnected
    End If
End Sub
```

In VB.NET 2010 I write:

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private Sub MainForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    AxSAPBAPIControl1.Connection.Logoff()
End Sub

    Private Sub AxSAPLogonControl1_ClickEvent(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     AxSAPLogonControl1.ClickEvent
        AxSAPBAPIControl1.Connection = AxSAPLogonControl1.NewConnection()
        AxSAPBAPIControl1.Connection.Client = "100"
        If AxSAPBAPIControl1.Connection.Logon(0, False) Then
            MsgBox(AxSAPBAPIControl1.Connection.IsConnected)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

and end up with:

> Eine Ausnahme (erste Chance) des Typs "System.AccessViolationException" ist in mscorlib.dll aufgetreten. in .Client = "100"

VB6 just works.

Does anyone have an idea how to transfer the Connection Object to the other class in VB.NET?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Getting help with COM servers crashing with an access violation requires support from the vendor.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But the Vendors to contact would be: Microsoft and SAP. What would be a rought guess about my chances to get them to address the problem? So probably I am better off in closing the connection and reopen it every time I need a different feature. I just would have liked to avoid this.

Comment: German "Eine Ausnahme..." translates into `An exception (first chance) of type "System.AccessViolationException" occurred in mscorlib.dll. in .client = "100"`

Answer (score -1):

At a guess:
You are using Set in old VB6 code, i think that affects objects, linke in VBA.
You might try something like

```
AxSAPBAPIControl1 =  AxSAPBAPIControl1.Connection = AxSAPLogonControl1.NewConnection()
```

I think AxSAPBAPIControl1 gives you a connection object and does not modify itself - so you are opening a new connection, which is never used, and then then the "unconnected" AxSAPBAPIControl1 is used.
I dont know SAP-Com, but this kind of krad is happening in msoffice.interop happening sometimes.
Please give me some feedback.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but VB refused because of typecasting error. Adding a CTYPE tpyecast led to a syntax error.